Big problems caused by Chinese usernames in Julia
I am a Chinese university student, I want to learn Julia, but my C disk path has Chinese, my user name is Chinese, and then when I download Pluto, it will always be automatically downloaded to the C disk, but my Julia is installed in the D disk, because there is no Chinese path in the d disk, and then when I follow the course later on, in the notebook, even if it's a simple operation, such as opening photos, it doesn't work. Then when I follow the course later, in the notebook, Pluto doesn't work even for very simple operations, such as opening photos. What should I do? Please tell me!
This is driving me crazy!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
I tried to change the startup.jl ,and add this: ENV["JULIA_DEPOT_PATH"] = "D:\Julia",and then I delete the .julia in C disk, but it never worked. I want to know what can I do to prevent Julia from continuing to use the path to the C drive.
here is part of the code that reported the error:(not swift)
Errors encountered while load FileIO.File{FileIO.DataFormat{:PNG}, String}("C:\\Users\\李峥嵘\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\jl_0XyfYPcT2j").
All errors:
===========================================
Failed to open C:\Users\李峥嵘\AppData\Local\Temp\jl_0XyfYPcT2j
===========================================
ArgumentError: Package ImageMagick [6218d12a-5da1-5696-b52f-db25d2ecc6d1] is required but does not seem to be installed:
 - Run `Pkg.instantiate()` to install all recorded dependencies.

===========================================
ArgumentError: Package OpenCV [f878e3a2-a245-4720-8660-60795d644f2a] is required but does not seem to be installed:
 - Run `Pkg.instantiate()` to install all recorded dependencies.

===========================================

Fatal error



I'm guessing that only happens on Windows, and it would happen with any non-ascii symbols in the path, such as äöüß?

It's a common problem in Windows. I would suggest a linux vm...

Sorry to hear that you are facing these difficulties!
I am trying to learn more about your problem, and it would really help to see which code you were running in the notebook. Could you share a notebook file that is not working?

My guess is your tempdir() for julia is on C:.
You can try to change the values of ENV["TMP"]  or TEMP or USERPROFILE
https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/file/#Base.Filesystem.tempdir

Specifically calling ENV["TMPDIR"] = "D:\Julia\tmp" before import Pluto should fix the tempdir problem.
